# how to find all strings matching a pattern in linux

Tags: linux, grep

Can one suggest a grep command for finding a string in a list of files by providing a part of the string?

I have a list of files in a directory which contains email addresses. I want to extract all email addresses ending with a particular domain name. for example, i want to get a list of all emails ending with "@google.com" in a file.

Directory contains N number of files. The data in each file is a single line seperated with a comma. I have tried so many options with grep command and none worked.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
grep -E -o "\b[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]+@google\.com\b" *.files
```

Basically include the list of characters in the `[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]` character class which constitutes acceptable email addresses.